# Second Equality of Wald

Tags: martingales

I'm doing an exercice about the second equality of Wald.

> Let $(X_i)_{i\ge 1}$ be a sequence of integrable random variables. Let $\mathcal{F} = (\mathcal{F}_i)_{i\ge 1}$ be a filtration such that $X$ is adapted. We suppose that $X_i$ and $F_{i-1}$ are independent for all $i\ge 2$ and that $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2] < \infty$.
>   We put $S_n := X_1 + ... + X_n$. Show that if $T$ is an integrable stopping time such as $T \ge 1$, then $\mathbb{E}[S_T ^2 - T\mathbb{E}[X_1 ^2]]^2 = \sigma ^2 (X_1)\mathbb{E}[T]$.

I would like to do it this way : Show that $Y_n := Z_n^2 - n\sigma (X_1)$ is a martingale, where $Z_n := X_1 + ... + X_n - n\mathbb{E}[X_1]$ is a martingale (this result as been shown in an other exercice).

But I can't show that. We have $\mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1} | F_n] = \mathbb{E}[Z_{n+1} ^2 - (n+1)\sigma ^2 (X_1) | F_n] = \mathbb{E}[Z_{n+1} ^2 | F_n] - (n+1)\sigma ^2 (X_1)$.
And then, I tried to develop the square, but I don't get any good result.... Maybe there is a mistake in the beginning ?

Thanks for your help.

P.S. I suppose there is another way to prove that equality, but I want to do it this way.

P.P.S As you can see, English is not my mother tongue, so if you see any mistake, I would be glad to learn how to write it correctly.

Here is the link to the same subject in Mathoverflow : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98711/second-equality-of-wald

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that this two sites were related. I added a link to Mathoverflow.

Comment: Thank you. I hope you'll get a good answer soon and a somewhat belated welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

- $Z_{n+1}^2=Z_n^2+2Z_n\bar X_{n+1}+\bar X_{n+1}^2$ where $\bar X_{n+1}=X_{n+1}-\mathrm E(X_1)$.
- $\mathrm E(Z_n^2\mid F_n)=\text{____}$.
- Since $\bar X_{n+1}$ is independent of $F_n$, $\mathrm E(Z_n\bar X_{n+1}\mid F_n)=\text{____}$ and $\mathrm E(\bar X_{n+1}^2\mid F_n)=\text{____}$.
- Hence $(Y_n)$ is an $(F_n)$-martingale.

**Edit:** There are two cases when the conditional expectation of the integrable random variable $U$ conditionally on the sigma-algebra $G$ is simple to determine.

- If $U$ is $G$-measurable, then $\mathrm E(U\mid G)=U$.
- If $U$ is independent of $G$, then $\mathrm E(U\mid G)=\mathrm E(U)$.

Comment: Hi did,
Thank you for the tips. The first step is ok.
Now for the second one, is there any formula to calculate $\mathbb{E}[Z_n ^2 |F_n]$ with a square in it ? Or maybe I just have to develop ?

Comment: I find that $\mathbb{E}[Z_n ^2 |F_n] = Z_n$

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: Is this possible that $\mathbb{E}[Z_n \bar{X_{n+1}}] = 0$ ?

Comment: I fail to see why you ask this but yes, if $U$ and $V$ are independent and $E(U)=0$ then $E(UV)=0$.

Comment: In fact, I just calculate and find that. I find it strange, so I asked :)

Comment: Beware that $Z_n\bar X_{n+1}$ is not independent on $F_n$ in general, since $\bar X_{n+1}$ is but $Z_n$ is not.

Comment: Okay thanks, that's a remark I have to keep in mind

Comment: For the last one, I find that $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}_{n+1}^2] = var(X_1)$ :
$\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}_{n+1}^2] = \mathbb{E}[(X_{n+1} - \mathbb{E}[X_1])^2])$
And since $X_1$ and $X_{n+1}$ have the same distribution

Comment: Sure, but let me note that your two last questions deal with expectations although you should be concerned with **conditional** expectations.

Comment: Of course, I just forgot to write it, sorry :(
But I write it correctly for my exercise

Comment: So the exercise is solved with your tips, thank you very much !! :)